# Strange graphics glitch when working with very small units(milimeters)

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, object-mode

It all works nicely until one point, then everything looks like on the image (both in edit and object mode). Even when I save and reopen the file. :S

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like Z-fighting. Could you upload blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Comment: Yep, Z-fighting caused either by duplicate geometry or inadequate viewport clipping values for your model scale

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3312" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3312/)

Comment: It's a different file but it has the same issue.
I haven't saved the model from the image :/

Comment: I don't see any issues on my computer, it may be something related to your Blender install, computer hardware, or drivers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you set the clip range to a very large value:

[image]

By setting the end clip to such a large value you are loosing precision. Blender can no longer resolve geometry that is close to each other. The issue is called Z-fighting, the same as when you have geometry that is occupying the same space in the scene (This happens in all 3D software not only in blender). As a rule your start and end clip settings should be so that they encompass your scene, but not a lot more. Why would you need to set the end distance to trillions of Km when you are working with objects are a few centimeters long?

Comment: My `End` clipping was fine, I just had to change the `Start`. Thank you very much!