# Black streaky artifacts in cycles renders

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering, shaders

I'm making some models for a model pack I'm working on, and there are black "streaks" all over my models. There are no overlapping faces, no hidden objects, or any duplicate vertices. The material is a simple diffuse and glossy shader, no texture. I have been stuck for a while, and I have no idea what to do. My mesh is pretty basic and subdivided, with quads only. [image]

Comment: Currently it could be a number of things. There are a few things you could try to at least rule out some causes. Try using a solid environment color, and not a texture. Try Removing the material on an object. Try decreasing the viewport clipping distance. If you isolate a single object with Numpad / does it still happen?

Comment: @Brenticus Thank you so much! The clipping "end" value was set to 3000 feet... I don't remember ever touching that value, but that was the source of my problem. Set that back to 10 and my problem went away.

Comment: Read this related post: [Strange graphics glitch when working with very small units(milimeters)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/79914/1853)