# Viewport Artifacts when working with big scales

Tags: 3d-view, units

Has anyone encountered those lines which look like z-fighting already? 
They only occur when the scale that is being worked on is relatively big.
When switching to orthographic this problem does not occur.

[image]

My island is 320x320m in size with `metric` as `Unit` and 1 as `Unit Scale`. 
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Are you referring to the orange selection outline getting weird in the valley and ocean, or are you referring to the fact that the map looks like stacked cardboard?

Comment: I am referring to the look of stacked cardboard, the orange outline is because I got a part of the island as a separate mesh to make it have a higher resolution

Comment: Most likely z-fighting due to a very large clip range. If you are working with Kilometers and have the minimum clip distance at 1mm you are giving up precision. If the start and end clip distance are set to a very wide range, 3D engines (blender included) will fail to differentiate faces that are very close together (here's an [example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21759/1853).
) Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106624 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79883/strange-graphics-glitch-when-working-with-very-small-unitsmilimeters/79914#79914

Comment: ahh I see, changed it to `Start: 1m` and `End: 1km` now it works ;) thanks.
If you post your comment as answer I'll accept it

Comment: @user1853 This was helpful for me as well .. I would never have thought that the clip range caused this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the clipping to:
`Start: 1m` and `End: 1km`
as suggested by @user1853 worked!